# What is the difference between && and || in JavaScript term?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

My classmate used "||" instead of "&&" for an if statement, but the result is the same. I tried to understand the differences by reading the article but I can't seem to understand them. I would appreciate if anyone can explain in an easy way...Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The logical && and || operators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41205110/the-logical-and-operators-in-javascript)

Comment: Can you write down the sample code which your classmate wrote so that I can give your a brief idea of it?

Comment: Check out MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: The `||` operator is logical OR. The expression `a || b` is `true` if *either* `a` or `b` is true. The `&&`is logical AND. The expression `a && b` is `true` if *both* `a` and `b` are true. If your friends condition was the same irregardless of `||` or `&&` was used, that shows that either the left- and right-hand side was both false, or both was true.

Answer (score 2):

&& is and operator and || is or operator 
&& work as

```
1 && 1= 1
1 && 0 = 0
0 && 1 = 0
0 && 0 = 0
```

|| work as

```
1 || 1= 1
1 || 0 = 1
0 || 1 = 1
0 || 0 = 0
```

where 1 , 0 are true and false 
we can understand it by the following example

suppose we have a code

```
if(1==1 && 2==2){}
```

so 1==1 is true means 1 and 2==2 is true means 1, so && operator work like this 
1 && 1 =1 hence the result will be true and execute if statement

Answer (score 0):

You could replace [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) with [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()) and vice versa, by using [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
!(a && b) = !a || !b 
!(a || b) = !a && !b
```

If you have

```
if (a || b)
```

you could use this without OR

```
if (!(!a && !b))
```

Comment: Thank you for additional tip!