# What does this syntax mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have JavaScript code and I found the following line :

I'm a bit confused about the syntax:

```
e = k.attr("data-icon"), e && (a.icon = e),
```

I understand the first part `k.attr("data-icon")` but not the rest.

What does that mean?

Comment: Do you ask about `,` or `&&` or both?

Comment: I ask for both please :)

Comment: see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561043/what-does-a-comma-do-in-javascript-expressions and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41205110/the-logical-and-operators-in-javascript

Comment: comma operator and logical and

Comment: The  e && (a.icon = e) means -> if e is truthy, set a.icon to the value of e. And `e` is the value of the previous assignment statement `k.attr('data-icon')`.  This should not have been marked as a duplicate.

Comment: This looks very much like minified code, not anything someone has written like that. Do not try to pick up this style. Try finding the un-minified *source* code instead and learn from there what the code is doing.