# Not understanding logical operators in a specific situation

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, logical-operators

I was looking into another person's code and found this specific part where I don't understand what the logic operators are being used for. (Mind that I'm still starting out with JavaScript, but also did as much research as I could before coming for your aid.)

```
const createStream = (options) => {
  const stream = new PassThrough({
    highWaterMark: options && options.highWaterMark || null,
  });
  stream.destroy = () => { stream._isDestroyed = true; };
  return stream;
};
```

So, as far as I understand, this is a function createStream(options), basically, and it creates a variable called stream, which is a stream.PassThrough object.

Now, the part that bugs me a bit is the `highWaterMark: options && options.highWaterMark || null,` part.
I simply don't understand any of this. I know how to use logical operators in if() statements for instance, but this just doesn't make sense to me, and I couldn't find a lot online to explain me this.

Appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The logical && and || operators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41205110/the-logical-and-operators-in-javascript)

Comment: It means, if there is no value present for options.highWaterMark, set the value of options.highWaterMark to null. This may be done to avoid undefined variables having unexpected effects. Also, a null value for options.highWaterMark could be being checked for elsewhere in the script to determine whether to show or hide some related element(s) in the document. It means you only have to check for null, rather than null or undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `&&` and `||` have the [same operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) and operate left-to-right. So

```
highWaterMark: options && options.highWaterMark || null,
```

is equivalent to

```
highWaterMark: (options && options.highWaterMark) || null,
```

Additionally, keep in mind that `&&` resolves to the left side if the left side is falsy, otherwise it resolves to the right side. So if `options` is `undefined`, `(options && options.highWaterMark)` resolves to `undefined`.

The `&&` is needed there because if the `options` parameter doesn't exist (eg `undefined` or `null`), simply doing

```
highWaterMark: options.highWaterMark || null,
```

would throw an error, because you can't access properties of `undefined` or `null`.

Then, for the `||` part: it will resolve to the left side if the left side is truthy, else it'll resolve to the right side. So there are two possible paths:

```
// options starts out undefined
  highWaterMark: options && options.highWaterMark || null,
// equivalent to
  highWaterMark: (options && options.highWaterMark) || null,
  highWaterMark: (undefined && options.highWaterMark) || null,
  highWaterMark: undefined || null,
  highWaterMark: null,
```

Or:

```
// options starts out as an object
  highWaterMark: options && options.highWaterMark || null,
// equivalent to
  highWaterMark: (options && options.highWaterMark) || null,
  highWaterMark: (options.highWaterMark) || null,
  highWaterMark: options.highWaterMark,
```

So, what the code does is it

- checks to see if the `options` variable is truthy
- If so, it assigns the `highWaterMark` property of `options` to the `highWaterMark` property of the object
- Otherwise, it assigns `null` to that property

It's equivalent to the following:

```
let highWaterMark;
if (options) {
  highWaterMark = options.highWaterMark;
} else {
  highWaterMark = null;
}
const stream = new PassThrough({ highWaterMark });
```

This allows callers of `createStream` to be either of the type:

```
createStream();
```

or

```
createStream({ highWaterMark: 'foo' });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! My brain melted for a second there trying to understand what you said, but after analyzing the page you sent me and trying to understand it, I finally do!